# Using "required" in sentences

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, I do not know if the preposition "for" after "required" is correct. I think I can use "to" after "required", but I do not know which one is more grammatically correct? Please help me out with this issue. Thanks!

> Solving the mentioned problems can contribute to finding key answers required for enabling this technology.

Answer (score 1):

The given phrasing is acceptable, but I think it's more common to use *to* with an infinitive verb:

> Solving the mentioned problems can contribute to finding key answers required *to enable* this technology.

Comment: It may be correct but it's awfully clunky. Why not trim it down to: *Solving these problems may help provide the key to enable this technology*. You make it much easier on your reader and the meaning is the same.

Comment: @RonaldSole Sure, there are lots of ways to phrase things. This isn't a forum on writing style, so I was just addressing the specific grammatical issue in the question.

Comment: @Barman Perfectly true. I retract the suggestion.